# Which cwebp parameters to specify to avoid loosing quality when converting pictures from JPEG?

Tags: jpeg, pictures, webp

I would like to convert all the pictures I've taken with my phone and DSLR cams from JPEG to WebP to save hard drive space. But I would like to make sure no quality is lost. What parameters should I specify?

`-q 100` produces a file just slightly smaller (not worth converting) than the original. `-lossless` produces a file slightly bigger than the original. `-q 50` produces a file much smaller than the original but I can clearly see sharpness loss if I zoom in. `-q 50` seems ok but there still is visible difference.

Comment: Every convert (when use lossy format) decrease the quality, better keep the originals (diskspace is so cheep those days)

Comment: An you are the only person who know how much lost of quality is acceptable for you

Comment: @RomeoNinov I would like the resulting webp to be visually identical to the original jpeg if possible.

Comment: Visually identical on pixel level? From distance? Even this differ from person to person. How many photo you want to convert to save space. 10000, 100000?

Comment: @RomeoNinov I understand pixel-perfect identicalness is hardly possible if I actually want to save space. I feel like being unable to easily spot a difference at 100% zoom (for 4128x2322 pictures) is enough. The quantity is roughly near 10000 (20000 perhaps, I can't remember). The total space they take is probably about some dozens of GiBs and I'd love to free a dozen or two up.

Comment: The best you can do is to try `-q 70` and `-q 80`  and check which one of them offer you better balance between size and quality. (in different product, Lightroom) i use 75% when export to JPEG and I am fine with quality

Comment: @RomeoNinov Thanks. Is `-m` ("compression method (0=fast, 6=slowest), default=4") or any other parameter worth tweaking? Don't you happen to know where I can find a good manual explaining every parameter, how do they affect the result and what are the reasonable combinations? Simple `-q 70`-`-q 80` is most probably enough but I'm somewhat curious about understanding the rest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89835/discussion-between-romeo-ninov-and-ivan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As feeling about the quality of the photo is strictly personal I can give some recommendations to be tested:

Check if `-q 70` or `-q 80` give you acceptable result. Or maybe `-q 90`. And compare the result quality and size.

Also you can play with `-m 0`, `-m 4` and `-m 6` (on image with lot of details) to check the results. This parameter may or may not have distinguishable effect on the result.

One more option is to try `-partition_limit 20` which can affect "flat" areas (in sense of colours). This will affect color gradations and can introduce so named [colour banding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colour_banding) so use it moderate (if use at all).